# Add carriage return using regex pattern of any number

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have text that looks like this:

```
3    Q    I think I started out, I said when4 you first noticed
the oyster beds, it sounded5 like it didn't really concern you, you did not6 believe that the dredging material or the berm7 building material could reach the oyster beds?8    A    That's correct.9    Q
```

I need to have an output that finds the first of any numeric sequence (i.e. "10" doesn't need to be a double match for 1 and 0) and looks looks like this (minus the spaces I had to put between each line):

```
3    Q    I think I started out, I said when

4 you first noticed the oyster beds, it sounded

5 like it didn't really concern you, you did not

6 believe that the dredging material or the berm

7 building material could reach the oyster beds?

8    A    That's correct.

9    Q
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try matching on the pattern:

```
(?<=.)(\d+)
```

This says to match and capture a number of any size, provided that it is not the first number in the text.  This avoids adding an unwanted newline before the first line beginning with `3`.  Then, we can replace with a newline followed by that captured number.  Here is a working script:

```
Dim regex As Regex = new Regex("(?<=.)(\d+)")
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("1 stuff10 more stuff", vbCrLf & "$1"))
```

This outputs:

```
1 stuff
10 more stuff
```

Be certain to include the `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` to be able to use `vbCrLf` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here, we might just want to capture the `(\d+)`, then replace it with a new line and `$1`:

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/N7gICX/1/).

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N7gICX/1/)

Comment: When I use the substitution the resulting text always adds "\n" to the number instead  of actually adding a carriage return - e.g. ""\n3 Q I think I started out, I said when\n4 you first noticed the oyster beds, it sounded\n5 like" - Any ideas why this would happen?